# Python, why does this line need a comma?

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

```
   u_list = input("put numbers: right now: ")
List = u_list.split(",")
t = tuple(List)
print("Tuple: ",t)
print("list: ",List)
```

why do you need a comma in front of the variable: t variable: List?
I mean the one where there is  ,t - comma in front of the t .

Comment: also, when I tried adding a "." in front of the variable t, it didn't work

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Are you talking about the `print`?  It's because you're passing two parameters to `print`.

Comment: yeah, thankyou for seeing my question